# Create a column in a different sheet for each sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4  sheets in my workbook. However I will add or remove sheets before sheet4. That is the only sheet that doesn't change. On this sheet I want to create a column for each sheet before sheet4. Column A for sheet1, column B for sheet2 and column C for Sheet3.

The first cell of each column should contain sheet name. I managed to do this but I'm unable to do the following: Whenever I delete a sheet the corresponding column created in sheet4 should be deleted and when I add a new sheet a new column should be created relative to the position in the workbook (if in between sheets 2 and 3 the column should be column C)

I would also like to insert a defined range like A1:A5, B1:B5 etc instead of a full column for each sheet, if is possible.

```
Sub Prepare2_Sheet()
    Dim sheetnum As Long
    sheetnum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Index - 1

    For i = 1 To sheetnum
        Sheet4.Columns(i).Insert
        Sheet4.Cells(1, i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i        
End Sub
```

Comment: While you can trigger new sheets with `Workbook_NewSheet` event and removing sheets with the `Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete` event you will run into issues if someone renames a sheet, because there is no event for renaming sheets.

Comment: The sheets will not be renamed.

Comment: Well you probably cannot prevent this (just assume that no one will do it), the same issue occurs when someone moves a sheet around (re orders them). If you can prevent renaming and re-sorting, then try to use the both events that I suggested to edit your columns. The index of the added (or deleted) sheet `sh.Index` in these events should give you the column number where to add/delete a column.

Comment: How do i add a column or delete one based on sh.Index?

Comment: As you added the other columns too (see your code). Instead of `i` use the index. Give it a try do some research and if you get stuck or errors come back and ask a question and show your code.